# How to return std::unique_ptr& from overloaded Subscripting [] Operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unique-ptr

I have a class World that has a vector which holds unique pointers to class Tile. World has a get function that returns a reference to the unique_ptr held by Vector.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "Tile.h"

class World
{
public:

    std::unique_ptr<Tile>& get(unsigned int i) { return Vector[i]; }

private:

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> Vector;

}
```

I wanted to replace the get function with an overloaded operator:

```
std::unique_ptr<Tile>& operator[](unsigned int i) { return Vector[i]; }
```

However I am getting the following error when I call World[i]:

```
error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Tile,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function with[_Ty=Tile]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not within the snippet you posted. Instead, the way to bind the return value of the `operator[]` to a variable is important. This code will fail,

```
World worldInstance;

// fill the Vector in worldInstance with elements...

auto element = worldInstance[0];
```

as it tries to copy a `std::unique_ptr<Tile>` object. `std::unique_ptr` is a move-only type, so the compiler complains about a deleted member function (the copy constructor). You can instead capture the return value as a reference,

```
auto& element = worldInstance[0];
```

or directly retrieve a reference to the pointee by

```
Tile& element = *worldInstance[0];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this answer is not clear to me. I have tried:     `std::unique_ptr<Tile>& World::operator[](unsigned int i) { auto& element = Vector[i]; return element; }` but I still get the same error.

Comment: No, you should leave the operator overload as it is. Just `return Vector[i];` is fine. The issue is how to deal with the return value.

Comment: I have to assign it every time I call World[i]?

Comment: No. You can't call `World[i]` because `World`  is a type. You can only invoke the operator overload with an _instance_ of `World`, as shown in the answer (the instance of `World` is called "worldInstance". My point is that you code compiles as you have shown it. The error is where you assign the return value of the operator overload to a variable.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the instance was implied when I said World[i]. Let's say the Tile class has a function foo() and I want to call `worldInstance[i]->foo()` ... do I first have to assign worldInstance[i] to an auto& or Tile& EVERY TIME I want to call foo? That's so ridiculous.

Comment: No, you don't have to assign it to a variable. You can directly invoke `worldInstance[i]->foo()`.

Comment: But I can't do that right now. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188512/discussion-between-lubgr-and-nathaniel-g-m).

Comment: On a side note, unless you actually need to transfer ownership of the `unique_ptr` to the caller, I wouldn't return a `unique_ptr` at all, reference or otherwise. I would return a pointer/reference to the actual `Tile` instead, eg: `Tile* get(unsigned int i) { return Vector[i].get(); }` ... `Tile* operator[](unsigned int i) { return Vector[i].get(); }`